# font family and font size in iOS tabbed page not applied in Xamarin form

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I tried to apply font family and font size in title  in tabbed page but not work ,
tried many articles but not work

https://gist.github.com/richseviora/ab10fd29e191ef1cad74cfa6064074f5

https://xamgirl.com/extending-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  Relevant code should be included in the body of your post, properly formatted, not included as a link to an external site

Comment: I understand you tried this multiple ways. Pick one attempt, add to your question the **exact code** that you typed. Then someone can help you figure out why it is not working for you.